# Pulsar boton con enter en JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, eventos

He construido una interfaz gráfica con un TextField y un Button en JavaFx. Al pulsar el botón se me imprime en consola lo que tiene el TextField. Quiero hacer esto mismo pero pulsando la tecla enter, es decir que quiero que la tecla enter y el botón hagan la misma función. El código es el siguiente.

```
public class Controller {

@FXML
private TextField areaEnvioTf;

public Controller(){

    EnviarConEnter();
}



public void EnviarConEnter(){

    areaEnvioTf.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
                System.out.println(areaEnvioTf.getText());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Intento introducir el método EnviarConEnter en el constructor pero me salta una NullPointerException.
Las líneas 23 y 16 corresponden a la llamada al método y a la linea en la que utilizo el método setOnKeyPressed.

```html
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sample.Controller.EnviarConEnter(Controller.java:23)
 at sample.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:16)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
 at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
 ... 17 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Puedes aportar el código donde llamas a tu función? para ver donde te salta la excepción.

Comment: Editado con el constructor

Comment: Podrias por favor añadir tambien el error completo, el mensaje con la línea de código que falla, normalmente se puede seguir el "Trace" del error para ver de donde procede.

Comment: He añadido la excepción que da esta clase ya que no me permite pegar todo el error.

Comment: La respuesta del compañero pol es la correcta. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el NullPointerException viene dado porque cuando estas intentando asignar en el constructor, setOnKeyPressed a tu Textfield el TextField aún no se ha cargado. Prueba a llamar a tu función EnviarConEnter dentro del método initialize, es un metodo que se ejecuta solo cuando se está cargando la clase(parecido a un constructor) para hacerlo debes implementar la interfaz de Initializable y hacer el override de initialize:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private TextField areaEnvioTf;

    public Controller(){

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        EnviarConEnter();
    }
    public void EnviarConEnter(){

    areaEnvioTf.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
                System.out.println(areaEnvioTf.getText());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

El código no esta comprobado ya que no tengo tu proyecto para poder ejecutarlo.